# autocompletion with libedit on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, autocomplete, terminal, readline

Here's a simple program that uses libedit or GNU readlines to generate autocompletion options

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *command_generator(char *word, int state) {
    char *options[] = {"I_love_math", "he_love_math", "she_loves_math", "they_love_math", NULL};
    return options[state] ? strdup(options[state]) : NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    rl_readline_name = "rl_example";
    rl_completion_entry_function = (void*)command_generator;
    rl_initialize();
    rl_parse_and_bind("TAB: menu-complete");
    while (1) {
        char *line = readline("rl> ");
        if (line == NULL) break;
        printf("echo %s\n", line);
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program works, in the sense it displays the completion options, however it does not actually complete them. That is, it will only display the available options

```
$ gcc -ggdb3 -ledit example.c && ./a.out
rl> a
he_love_math    I_love_math     she_loves_math  they_love_math
rl> a
```

Even after I press tab, it does not relace "a" with "he_love_math", it just shows the options.

From a small internet search, I found out that one needs to bind the TAB key to menu-complete, however as you can see, neither running

```
rl_parse_and_bind("TAB: menu-complete");
```

not putting "TAB: menu-complete" in my home directory helps here.

How can I make completion work? How can I cause `libedit` to replace the current word with the completion suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**readline** on OSx is implemented via routines in libedit aka editline.
Unfortunately the compatibility does not extend as far as the configuration commands.

Change your binding line to:

```
rl_parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete");
```

or put this in `~/.editrc`

```
bind ^I rl_complete
```

Read the man page for `editline` and `editrc`; but they don't have information on the `rl_*` routines in the library `libedit`